# Solving inequalities in arithmetic

Tags: inequality

If

$$S_S \ge \frac{120x}{\frac{60}{x}+1}$$

and

$2x\le 45$

then what can be said about the range of $S_S$?

Comment: Can $x$ be negative ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, x here is a positive quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For positive $x$, the numerator is a growing function and the denominator a decreasing one, so that the ratio is growing.

Hence,

$$\frac{120\cdot0}{\frac{60}{0}+1}\le S_S\le\frac{120\frac{45}2}{60\frac2{45}+1}.$$

(Though the lower bound is meaningless as written, the limit is $0$.)

Comment: What about values of x such that $0<x<1$? In these cases, the numerators  are decreasing.

Comment: Could you please tell the source/chapters from where I can lerarn the analysis the way you did.

Comment: @Soumee: no, they aren't.

Comment: Sorry for the typo.

Comment: So, you vary x from 0 to 45 and see if the numerator or the denominator is an increasing or decreasing function.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5dx7u9pqil).

$$S_s(a)>S_s(b) \space \text{for} \space a,b>0, a>b.$$

Hence the max on the positive is $S_s(22.5)=\frac{8100}{11}$

We see $x=0$ cannot exist due to $\frac{60}{x}$ on the denominator.

Hence $$0<S_s\le\frac{8100}{11}$$

Comment: How can you tell $S_s(a)>S_s(b) \space \text{for} \space a,b>0, a>b.$?

Comment: The graph shows it well. For an algebraic example, note that in the numerators, $120a>120b$ if $a>b$, and also, that $\frac{60}{b}>\frac{60}{a}$. Hence for $S_s (a)$, we multiply by more and divide by less than in $S_s(b)$, and so our result is greater.